# queryset object not callable Django

Tags: python, django, search, navbar

I wanted to make a search bar which search the database for queries in django and have come up with this so far:

view:

```py
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'patients/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_patients'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = patient.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')

        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(First_Name__icontains=query) |
                Q(Surname__icontains=query) |
                Q(DOB__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
            return queryset

        else:
            return patient.objects.all()
```

and my button on my template:

```html
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="get" action="{% url 'patients:index' %}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

and the model:

```py
class patient(models.Model):

    TITLE_CHOICES = (
        ('Mr', 'Mr'),
        ('Mrs', 'Mrs'),
        ('Ms', 'Ms'),
        ('Miss', 'Miss'),
    )

    Title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)
    First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    Surname = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    DOB = models.DateField()
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('patients:patientInfo', kwargs={"pk":self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.First_Name + " " + self.Surname
```

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: 'QuerySet' object is not callable

I have no clue what I am doing wrong and am very new to Django.

Comment: Hi! You are doing a class based view inheriting from Django LoginMixin and Generic view classes...   this is no beginner stuff. The error comes from the LoginRequireMixin class you inherit from in your view. Double check if you really need this, otherwise go check this class docs.

Comment: @Tico none of your comment is true. The traceback shows no indication that the LoginRequired mixin is to blame; and using it is a perfectly valid thing for a beginner to do.

Comment: The code you have posted looks ok to me. Are you sure that's what you're running. Make sure you have saved your files and restarted the server.

Comment: Uh...  you guys are right.  Maybe try: return list(queryset)  or return list(queryset.values()) might fix it.

Comment: Hi guys, It turns out it was a simple issue, rather than 'queryset', i should have been using 'all_patients' as in my index.html, i was using 'if all_patients'. Thank for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when I added a property, then it's a method and can't be callable

```
@property
def get_queryset(self):
```

so I fixed it by removing the property